# Create table from two list into dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

i am new to python and i want to create a dataframe from two list below.

```
my_foldername = ['folder1','folder2']
my_filetype = ['avi.txt','bmp.txt','exe.txt','avi.txt','bmp.txt','exe.txt']
```

here is my current line of code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(my_hostname,my_fileType)))
```

i would like to have this kind of output.

```
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|FolderName|   AVI    |    BMP   |    EXE   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| folder1  | avi.txt  | bmp.txt  | exe.txt  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| folder2  | avi.txt  | bmp.txt  | exe.txt  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
```

Comment: If you surround your code in ```  ``` it will render as code in the post. Please edit so your code is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as you tried to, but you first need to break the second list in chunks. In python 3.12+ this is easily done with [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html?highlight=batched#itertools.batched):

```
from itertools import batched

n = len(my_filetype)//len(my_foldername)

out = pd.DataFrame([[f, *t] for f,t
                    in zip(my_foldername, batched(my_filetype, n))],
                   columns=['FolderName', 'AVI', 'BMP', 'EXE'])
```

Output:

```
  FolderName      AVI      BMP      EXE
0    folder1  avi.txt  bmp.txt  exe.txt
1    folder2  avi.txt  bmp.txt  exe.txt00
```

If you don't have the latest python version (<3.12), use the `batched` recipe:

```
from itertools import islice

def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch
```

Alternatively, with a simple loop and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
n = len(my_filetype)//len(my_foldername)

out = pd.DataFrame([[f, *my_filetype[i*n:(i+1)*n]] for i,f
                    in enumerate(my_foldername)],
                   columns=['FolderName', 'AVI', 'BMP', 'EXE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.reshape` to change `my_filetype` into a 2 x 3 array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.reshape(my_filetype, (2, 3)),
    columns=["AVI", "BMP", "EXE"],
    index=pd.Series(my_foldername, name="FolderName"),
).reset_index()
```

If `my_filetype` has many more elements and you don't want to calculate the number of rows manually, you can supply -1 to tell numpy to do it for you:

```
np.reshape(my_filetype, (-1, 3))
```

Comment: Using `len(columns)` instead of `3` might be more generic too

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a dictionary and then convert it into a DataFrame using the Pandas library as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

my_foldername = ['folder1', 'folder2']
my_filetype = ['avi.txt', 'bmp.txt', 'exe.txt', 'avi.txt', 'bmp.txt', 'exe.txt']

data = {}

for file_type in my_filetype:
    file_extension = file_type.split('.')[0].upper()
    data[file_extension] = data.get(file_extension, []) + [file_type]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.insert(0, 'FolderName', my_foldername)
df = df.fillna('')

print(df)
```

This is the output for the above code:

[image]